# Correct query for group by user, per month

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB collection that stores documents in this format:

```
"name" : "Username",
"timeOfError" : ISODate("...")
```

I'm using this collection to keep track of who got an error and when it occurred.

What I want to do now is create a query that retrieves errors per user, per month or something similar. Something like this:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "_id": "$name",
        "errorsPerMonth": [
            {
                "month": "0",
                "errorsThisMonth": 10
            },
            {
                "month": "1",
                "errorsThisMonth": 20
            }
        ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I have tried several different queries, but none have given the desired result. The closest result came from this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
                  [
                    { 
                        $group: 
                        {
                            _id: { $month: "$timeOfError"},
                            name: { $push: "$name" },
                            totalErrorsThisMonth: { $sum: 1 }
                        } 
                    }
                  ] 
);
```

The problem here is that the `$push` just adds the username for each error. So I get an array with duplicate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compound the `_id` value in [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "name": "$name",
            "month": { "$month": "$timeOfError" }
        },
        "totalErrors": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The `_id` is essentially the "grouping key", so whatever elements you want to group by need to be a part of that.

If you want a different order then you can change the grouping key precedence:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "month": { "$month": "$timeOfError" },
            "name": "$name"
        },
        "totalErrors": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Or if you even wanted to or had other conditions in your pipeline with different fields, just add a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) pipeline stage at the end:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "month": { "$month": "$timeOfError" },
            "name": "$name"
        },
        "totalErrors": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id.name": 1, "_id.month": 1 } }
])
```

Where you can essentially [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works great and is much simpler than what I thought. But I'm wondering if I can group the names together? So that I don't get a separate result for each combination of name and $month. And also, how do I sort the result based on name or month?
Thanks.

Comment: @NoClueBlue More information based on your comments. Up-vote if you find things helpful, please.

Comment: Had to use `{ "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }` to make the sort work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NoClueBlue Thanks for addressing the typo I made in the sort. The explicit form is updated.